# How to show the Laplacian is a self-adjoint linear operator

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplacian, line-integrals, greens-theorem, self-adjoint-operators

I'm trying to prove the following: $$\iint_R(\phi_1\nabla^2\phi_2-\phi_2\nabla^2\phi_1)\ dR = 0$$

For $ 0 < x < L, 0 < y < H$. Given $\phi_i(x,y) $ satisfying the boundary conditions 
$$
\phi_i(x,0) = 0 = \phi_i(x,H) \ \ ||| \ \frac{\partial \phi_i}{\partial x}(0,y) = 0 = \frac{\partial \phi_i}{\partial x}(L,y)
$$

where the $\phi_i(x,y) $ also satisfy $$\nabla^2 \phi_i + \lambda_i \phi_i = 0 $$

---

This is what I've done so far:

$$\iint_R(\phi_1\nabla^2\phi_2-\phi_2\nabla^2\phi_1)\ dR = \oint_{\partial R}(\phi_1\nabla\phi_2-\phi_2\nabla\phi_1) \cdot \textbf{n} \ ds$$ which is deduced from Green's Second Theorem.
My issue is how to evaluate this last line integral given that there's the gradient and I don't know the normal vector.

Comment: It really just suffices to integrate by parts twice on the first term $\phi_{1} \nabla^{2} \phi_{2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\oint_{\partial R} (\phi_1\nabla\phi_2-\phi_2\nabla\phi_1)\cdot \mathbf{n}$ = $$\int_{A} (\phi_1\nabla\phi_2-\phi_2\nabla\phi_1)\cdot \mathbf{n} \ d\sigma + \int_{C} (\phi_1\nabla\phi_2-\phi_2\nabla\phi_1)\cdot \mathbf{n} \ d\sigma$$

Where A and C are the vertical borders of the rectangle (our domain). Here, we use boundary conditions, that's why horizontal borders disappear.
But the two remaining integrals have null integrands : $\phi_1\nabla\phi_2-\phi_2\nabla\phi_1$ is a $y$ coordinate vector, and the normal vector is a $x$ coordinate vector (since A and C are the vertical borders), so the dot product is null.

Comment: Hi! Could you please explain why the integrand is a $y$ coordinate vector?

Comment: Because we are integrating on the rectangle border, boundary conditions says that there is no $x$ coordinate (partial diffentials are the coordinates of the gradient). (EDIT : I mistaked vertical and horizontal sry )

Comment: Okay, I get that, but how do you get to the point to have to evaluate both the gradient and the functions at the endpoints?

Comment: Mmmh, i'm not sure to understand you're complain :( . The $\phi$ function is scalar function so no matter what it is when you consider the $\nabla \phi \cdot \mathbf{n}$ product.

Comment: So basically how do I convert those integrals into nice Riemann integrals that I know how to compute? Sorry for all the doubts!

Comment: Use parametric equation of A and C ! (very easy to find since A and C are segments), but in fact, you don't need to do that because a Jacobian will appear ... and the null dot product will still be there :)

Comment: I still can't manage to get it, if you could please type in the math...

Comment: $\int_{\varphi(U)} f(\mathbf{v})\, d\mathbf{v}
= \int_U f(\varphi(\mathbf{u})) \left|\det(D\varphi)(\mathbf{u})\right| \,d\mathbf{u}.$ The right side is a Riemann integral, the choice of $\varphi$ is quite obvious ... a segment parametric equation